# How to assign class if input is invalid?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML element:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="form.artist" ng-class="form.artist.$invalid ? 'error' : ''" required ng-minlength="4">
```

But it does not work when I have invalid input  `"form.artist"`

Comment: You should update your question or mark an answer as accepted so other know the issue is resolved. You'll also gain reputation points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form name="demoForm">

<input type="text" name="demoForm.artist" ng-model="form.artist" ng-class="{'yourclassname': demoForm.artist.$invalid && demoForm.artist.$dirty}">

</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: Also, be sure to indicate how it differs from the other answers, which also show the use of `ng-class`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

`<div ng-class="{'class-name': 'condition'(boolean)}" </div>`

In your case
`<input type="text" ng-model="form.artist" ng-class="{'class-name':'form.artist.$invalid}">`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `ng-class` attribute another way:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="form.artist" ng-class="{'error': form.artist.$invalid}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a `name` attribute to your `input`, then your `$invalid` flag comes of `[formName].[inputName].$invalid`:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="artist" required
           ng-minlength="4"
           ng-model="form.artist" 
           ng-class="myForm.artist.$invalid ? 'error' : ''" />
    <!-- or ng-class="{error:myForm.artist.$invalid}" -->
</form>
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38hdzga8/)

See also [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state) of angular:

> Similarly, an input control that has the ngModel directive holds an instance of NgModelController. Such a control instance can be published as a property of the form instance using the name attribute on the input control. The name attribute specifies the name of the property on the form instance.

Comment: This is my sample, that does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/38hdzga8/1/

Comment: As I said in my answer, you have to add a `name` attribute, see this working in your sample: https://jsfiddle.net/38hdzga8/2/